# pandas query single output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (called smalls) that is repurposed several times to create several network diagrams from a dataset.  I am trying to set the color of the nodes in one of the diagrams based on entity type and need to query the original dataframe.  However, when I do so it results in a series, which I then cannot perform a comparison on.  How can I modify the first line below to only give me the first entry from the dataframe (all of the others will be the same)?

```
temp=smalls.Role[smalls.Entity==big_nodes_order[i]]

print(temp)
10    Threat
11    Threat
12    Threat
Name: Role, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
temp=smalls.Role[smalls.Entity==big_nodes_order[i]]
print temp
10    Threat
11    Threat
12    Threat
Name: Role, dtype: object

print temp.iloc[0]
Threat

print temp.iat[0]
Threat

print temp.iloc[:1]
10    Threat
Name: Role, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I don't know why it didn't occur to me to treat the answer like a series and just deal with it.  I was very focused on trying to get the value of temp to be only one thing that I overlooked the obvious.  Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use `.head()` method:

```
temp=smalls.Role[smalls.Entity==big_nodes_order[i]].head(1)
```